# VBA Vlookup to work faster

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code in vba that works well but it is slow so I am looking for a better solution to this code.

If there is any one who could help me I would be grateful!

```
Sub Formula()


Sheets("Result").Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DATA!C[2]:C[86],3,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],DATA'!C[1]:C[85],4,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],DATA!C:C[84],13,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],DATA!C[-5]:C,6,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],DATA!C[-2]:C[82],21,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],DATA!C[-3]:C[81],22,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],DATA!C[-4]:C[80],24,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-9],DATA!C[-5]:C[79],25,FALSE)" 

Sheets("Result").Range("L2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10],DATA!C[-6]:C[78],44,FALSE)" 

Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Result").Range("A2:L" & LastRowColumnA).Select
Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: use [named ranges](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/11/excel-name-named-range-define-use/) if possible to make your ranges more descriptive (and also diminish the risk of confusion).

And perhaps try the [UsedRange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange?view=vsto-2017) argument rather than selecting whole columns down to the last row. The overly broad selection is wasteful and could be a cause of slowdown. I am on Linux now, so I
can't test. But make sure you are not making calculations for nothing. Focus on the range that is effectively in use and holding data, not the whole sheet.

Something else: the relative references. For example:

```
VLOOKUP(RC[-3],
```

means if I am not wrong: the current row and 3 columns to the left. I am wondering if this could be faster if written in plain A1 notation instead, so Excel doesn't have to compute the value. This is a question, I really don't know but it's something I might want to try.

Answer (score 0):

This should run faster. If any of the applications I turn off at the start is messing up with the functionality of the macro delete it.

```
Sub Formula()

'turn off applications not required
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Activesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

With Sheets("Result")

.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],DATA!C[2]:C[86],3,FALSE)" 
.Range("E2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],DATA'!C[1]:C[85],4,FALSE)" 
.Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],DATA!C:C[84],13,FALSE)" 
.Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],DATA!C[-5]:C,6,FALSE)" 
.Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],DATA!C[-2]:C[82],21,FALSE)" 
.Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],DATA!C[-3]:C[81],22,FALSE)" 
.Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],DATA!C[-4]:C[80],24,FALSE)" 
.Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-9],DATA!C[-5]:C[79],25,FALSE)" 
.Range("L2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10],DATA!C[-6]:C[78],44,FALSE)" 

End With

Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
LastRowColumnA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Result").Range("A2:L" & LastRowColumnA).Select
Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'turn applications back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Activesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It's strongly recommended that you store the _current_ values of the `Application` settings, then restore them to their previous values, instead of resetting them to a predetermined set of values.

Comment: Also you can avoid `Select`ing and the clipboard when pasting values: `With Sheets("Result").Range("A2:L" & LastRowColumnA)`, `.Value = .Value`, `End With`.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup

- The two 'Source Lookup Ranges' (`"F2:Flr"`, `"B2:Blr"`), the ranges where you try to find a match, stay as ranges (because `Application.Match` is faster on ranges) while the rest is written to arrays. The results are written to the 'Destination Array' (`dData`) which is then, in one go, written to the 'Destination Range'.
- Adjust (double-check) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookup()
    
    Const sName As String = "Data"
    Const slFirst1 As String = "F2"
    Const slFirst2 As String = "B2"
    Const sl2ColIndex As Long = 3 ' in connection to "B2" and ...,G,...
    Const sColsList As String = "H,I,R,G,Z,AA,AC,AD,AW"
    
    Const dName As String = "Result"
    Const dlFirst As String = "B2"
    Const dFirst As String = "D2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = RefColumnRange(dws.Range(dlFirst))
    If dlrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlrg.Rows.Count
    Dim dlData As Variant: dlData = GetColumnRange(dlrg)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sCols)
    
    Dim slrg1 As Range: Set slrg1 = RefColumnRange(sws.Range(slFirst1))
    
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(0 To nUpper)
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To nUpper + 1)
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim rIndex As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    If Not slrg1 Is Nothing Then
        For n = 0 To nUpper
            If n <> sl2ColIndex Then
                Set crg = slrg1.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(n))
                sData(n) = GetColumnRange(crg)
            End If
        Next n
        For r = 1 To drCount
            rIndex = Application.Match(dlData(r, 1), slrg1, 0)
            If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
                For n = 0 To nUpper
                    If n <> sl2ColIndex Then
                        dData(r, n + 1) = sData(n)(rIndex, 1)
                    End If
                Next n
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    
    Dim slrg2 As Range: Set slrg2 = RefColumnRange(sws.Range(slFirst2))
    
    If Not slrg2 Is Nothing Then
        n = sl2ColIndex
        Set crg = slrg2.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(n))
        sData(n) = GetColumnRange(crg)
        For r = 1 To drCount
            rIndex = Application.Match(dlData(r, 1), slrg2, 0)
            If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
                dData(r, n + 1) = sData(n)(rIndex, 1)
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    
    With dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(, nUpper + 1)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1) _
            .Offset(drCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub

Function RefColumnRange( _
    ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    With FirstCellRange.Cells(1)
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumnRange = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function

Function GetColumnRange( _
    ByVal ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = ColumnRange.Rows.Count
    Dim cData As Variant
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            cData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    GetColumnRange = cData
End Function
```